# Print page number using CSS

Tags: html, css

I just want to print page numbers using media print. I have tried all Stack Overflow solutions and no one work for me.

```css
.page-footer::before {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -52px;
  left: 90%;
  counter-increment: page;
  content: "Page " counter(page);
} 
.page-footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right:0; 
  width: 98.5%;
  height: 70px;
  counter-reset: page;
}
body {
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  margin: 0;
  counter-reset: page;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-footer">
    <table style="width: 100%; border-top: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100%; padding: 10px; font-family: Times New Roman, serif; font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold;" align="center">Footer</td>
            <td id="datetime"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And I m not getting output as expected, only first page is increment and rest of the pages follow the same number. Please suggest me a good solution.

Comment: Just because you are using the same CSS on both HTML pages does not mean the CSS shares memory.

Comment: sorry my friend, I don't have much time to spend on this, but I was looking into this: https://jsfiddle.net/LeonVFX/zscoopoc/ which might help, simple need small amount of js/jQuery.

Comment: @ROOT, i have tried this already but no worries  thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: @StackSlave, whats your suggestion to solve this issue sir

Comment: Don't even use CSS, like that. Just put the numbers on the pages in HTML.